# How to run a Maven plugin after mvn gatling:test

Tags: maven, pom.xml, gatling

I need to run a Maven plugin after Gatling(gatling-maven-plugin) runs to do some cleanup of my target dir.

From the following article it is called out that mvn gatling:test is bound to the integration-test phase of Maven
https://github.com/gatling/gatling/blob/65524556b1aaee7d129cc9c4794977468493ad34/src/sphinx/extensions/maven_plugin.rst#usage

Knowing this and that plugins tied to the same phase run sequentially I added a plugin after gatling-maven-plugin tied to the same integration-test phase.

Unfortunately that plugin never runs.  Appreciate any advice on how to get a plugin to run after gatling-maven-plugin runs.

Snippet of what i'm trying to do below.  Appreciate any advice.  I do something similar and successfully with the maven-surefire-plugin by adding a plugin after that tied to the test phase and it works perfect.  Scratching my head on this one.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>io.gatling</groupId>
  <artifactId>gatling-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <simulationsFolder>src/test/java</simulationsFolder>
    <includes>
      <include>perf.Test</include>
    </includes>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.8</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>myId</id>
      <phase>integration-test</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>run</goal>
        <configuration>
          <target>
            <echo message="running something after gatling"/>
          </target>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

I find it strange that the plugin never runs.

Anyway, for cleaning up, I would use the `post-integration-test` phase.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work.  Inspecting this plugins code it definitely seems tied to the 'integration-test' phase.  https://github.com/gatling/gatling-maven-plugin/blob/4f9ed0439741cc5572222fe611956a33ebd669d3/src/main/java/io/gatling/mojo/GatlingMojo.java#L52  Can a plugin block a downstream phase?  Any other ideas I can try?

Comment: I meant to change the phase of your antrun plugin to `post-integration-test`.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  Just making a point on the Gatling mojo.  I tried all 3(pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test) on the antrun plugin and all of them are ignored.

Comment: Are you sure you put the definitions into `<plugins>`, not `<pluginManagement>`?

Comment: Yes they are in <plugins>.  I believe I know what is going on here.  mvn gatling:test is calling the 'test' goal of that plugin directly.  And because you are calling the plugin:goal directly regardless of that plugin being tied to 'integration-test' phase will not additionally call other plugins tied to 'integration-test'

Comment: For now i've solved this by polluting my command line with: mvn gatling:test antrun:run@myId

Comment: ok, that's true. If you call `mvn plug:in`, only that plugin will run. All that binding to phases etc. does not play any role then. It only matters if you call a phase, like in `mvn install`.

Answer (score 0):

same issue with teardown. Managed to do it within in gatling itself, but doesnt seem as perfect cleanup achieved! also interaction between the gatling and other plugins not possible during post-integration-phase. once gatling tests are started then the entire execution control ends with the same plugin.